# How can I disable @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars rule with react dev server

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint, eslintrc, typescript-eslint

When I run the linter command, the below configuration works.
But when I have my react dev server running it compiles with warnings - "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars".

How can I remove the warnings?

Here is my **.eslintrc.js** configuration.

```
module.exports = {
    parser: "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    parserOptions: {
        ecmaVersion: 2020,
        sourceType: "module",
        ecmaFeatures: {
            jsx: true
        }
    },
    settings: {
        react: {
            version: "detect"
        }
    },
    extends: [
        "plugin:react/recommended",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
        "prettier/@typescript-eslint",
        "plugin:prettier/recommended"
    ],
    rules: {
        "@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/interface-name-prefix": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": "off"
    }
};
```

Comment: if using CRA, there's an [open issue about it](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6958).. it contains a workaround too, if it helps

Answer (score -1):

You need to disable `no-unused-vars` beforehand, as mentioned [in the docs](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-unused-vars.md).

```
{
  // note you must disable the base rule as it can report incorrect errors
  "no-unused-vars": "off",
  "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": ["error"]
}
```

Comment: The OP's question states that they're getting warnings from @typescript-eslint, so I don't think this is the issue

Comment: Because the error they're getting is being reported by ts eslint. Disabling the vanilla eslint won't help with that

Comment: And because React Dev Server ignores eslint config files

Comment: Yes your recommendation is a good one in general but I don't think it's causing this specific problem

Answer (score -3):

Try replacing `"@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": "off"` with `"@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": 0,`